Why Raycast hit did not assign limits from my script when I raycast a gameobject
I make a Door logic for my game using RaycastHit from mouse left button to open the door (or assign the Hinge Joint limits which are declared as float types in the class), but the problem is that I can raycast the Door Gameobject but the script didn't assign the limits for hinge on raycasted object. The scene Hinge component is setup correctly on the Door Gameobject I use for raycasting and also I use layermask to filler raycast gameobjects.
public float MAX_OPEN = 70f;
public float MIN_OPEN =0f;
RaycastHit hit;
HingeJoint m_hinge;
if(hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<HingeJoint>() !=null)
{
   m_hinge=hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
   JointLimits m_limits =m_hinge.limits;
   m_limits.min = MAX_OPEN;
   m_limits.max = MIN_OPEN;
   m_hinge.limits = m_limits;
}

I tried to get Debug.log from raycasted gameobject and unity console prints the name of the raycasted gameobject

Then it didnt find a hingejoint
